# Java: Complete Sudoku Generator, what I am missing here?

Tags: java, sudoku

I'm working on sudoku project and I found this:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23206/Sudoku-Algorithm-Generates-a-Valid-Sudoku-in

I converted that code into java but I just can't see where I have made mistake...

It almost works but it still places few numbers on same lines.

[image]

I have been stuggling with this sudoku generator for some time, I just can't see where I have done mistake, first I converted that vb.net code to C# and it worked fine.

Here is my java code (I left out code that produces grid):

```
private static JTextField sudoku[][] = new JTextField[9][9];
public static List<Square> sudokuGrid = new ArrayList<Square>();

public static void GenerateGrid(){
    Square[] Squares = new Square[81];

    for(int i = 0; i <= 80; i++){
        Squares[i] = new Square();
    }

    List<List<Integer>> available = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    int c = 0;

    for(int x = 0; x <= 80; x++){
        available.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
        for(int i = 1; i <= 9; i++){
            available.get(x).add(i);
        }
    }

    while(!(c == 81)){
        if(available.get(c).size() != 0){
             int i = GetRan(0, available.get(c).size() - 1);
             int z = available.get(c).get(i);

             if (Conflicts(Squares, Item(c, z)) == false){
                 Squares[c] = Item(c, z);
                 available.get(c).remove(i);
                 c += 1;
             }else{
                 available.get(c).remove(i);
             }
        }else{
             for (int y = 1; y <= 9; y++){
                 available.get(c).add(y);
             }
             Squares[c - 1] = new Square();
             c -= 1;
        }

        int j = 0;

        for (j = 0; j <= 80; j++)
        {
            sudokuGrid.add(Squares[j]);
        }
    }

}

private static boolean Conflicts(Square[] CurrentValues, Square test){

    for (Square s : CurrentValues){
        if ((s.Across != 0 && s.Across == test.Across) || (s.Down != 0 && s.Down == test.Down) || (s.Region != 0 && s.Region == test.Region)){
            if (s.Value == test.Value){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}

private static Square Item(int n, int v){
    Square functionReturnValue = new Square();
    n += 1;
    functionReturnValue.Across = GetAcrossFromNumber(n);
    functionReturnValue.Down = GetDownFromNumber(n);
    functionReturnValue.Region = GetRegionFromNumber(n);
    functionReturnValue.Value = v;
    functionReturnValue.Index = n - 1;
    return functionReturnValue;
}

public static int GetAcrossFromNumber(int n){
    int k = 0;
    k = n % 9;
    if (k == 0)
        return 9;
    else
        return k;
}


public static int GetDownFromNumber(int n){
    int k = 0;
    if (GetAcrossFromNumber(n) == 9)
    {
        k = n / 9;
    }
    else
    {
        k = n / 9 + 1;
    }
    return k;
}

private static int GetRegionFromNumber(int n){
    int k = 0;
    int a = GetAcrossFromNumber(n);
    int d = GetDownFromNumber(n);

    if (1 <= a && a < 4 && 1 <= d && d < 4) {
        k = 1;
    } else if (4 <= a && a < 7 && 1 <= d && d < 4) {
        k = 2;
    } else if (7 <= a && a < 10 && 1 <= d && d < 4) {
        k = 3;
    } else if (1 <= a && a < 4 && 4 <= d && d < 7) {
        k = 4;
    } else if (4 <= a && a < 7 && 4 <= d && d < 7) {
        k = 5;
    } else if (7 <= a && a < 10 && 4 <= d && d < 7) {
        k = 6;
    } else if (1 <= a && a < 4 && 7 <= d && d < 10) {
        k = 7;
    } else if (4 <= a && a < 7 && 7 <= d && d < 10) {
        k = 8;
    } else if (7 <= a && a < 10 && 7 <= d && d < 10) {
        k = 9;
    }
    return k;
}

public static int GetRan(int lower, int upper){
    Random rand = new Random();
    return rand.nextInt((upper - lower) + 1) + lower;
}


public void newGame() {
    for (int x = 0; x <= 8; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y <= 8; y++) {
            sudoku[x][y].setEditable(true);
            sudoku[x][y].setText("");
        }
    }

    sudokuGrid.clear();
    GenerateGrid();

    for(Square s : sudokuGrid){
        for(int x = 0; x <= 8; x++){
            for(int y = 0; y <= 8; y++){
                int index = s.Index;
                if(sudoku[x][y].getName().equals(String.valueOf(index))){
                    sudoku[x][y].setText(String.valueOf(s.Value));
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}

class Square{

    public int Across;
    public int Down;
    public int Region;
    public int Value;
    public int Index;

}
```

Some help please :)

Comment: What the problem / error you getting ?

Comment: It's placing same numbers on same lines as showed on picture. It should place numbers from 1 to 9 each line and 3x3 grid.

Comment: There should not be duplicates on vertical lines also.

Comment: What does the Square class look like?

Comment: Looks like every row has a duplicated value, not just the highlighted ones.

Comment: I updated code with Square class.

Comment: If you find 2 duplicate values in a 3x3 grid. Swap them then you would get the correct output ... Eg: in the middle column top 3x3 grid has two (2 & 6) duplicate values you should swap them.

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely at the linked code in `GenerateGrid`:

```
int j = 0;

for (j = 0; j <= 80; j++)
{
    sudokuGrid.add(Squares[j]);
}
```

should come after the `while(c != 81)` loop. In your code, it is inside the loop.

This means that you're adding too many squares to `sudokuGrid`. To check that this is happening, print the size of `sudokuGrid` at the end of the method -- it'll be a lot greater than 81.

#### Edit:

Also, there might be problems with the way you're displaying the board. Try this at the end of `newGame`, after the `GenerateGrid` call:

```
for(int x = 0; x <= 8; x++) {
    for(int y = 0; y <= 8; y++) {
        sudoku[x][y].setText("" + sudokuGrid.get(x * 9 + y).Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but sadly it didnt make any difference.

Comment: I added another issue. Does it fix the problem?

Comment: Thanks but problem still exists, didnt make any difference.

Comment: I should have printed sudoku like in your link. I found out the problem. Its caused by how I show textboxes on my application. It sends each 3x3 set to own grid, instead of own line. Mayby this image explains it better: http://i.imgur.com/2vVNEQm.jpg